# Nested ArgumentParser

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm trying to build nested parsers for a command line tool. I'm currently using `add_subparsers`, but it seems not powerful enough for one specific case. I cannot add same named arguments to both the parent parser and subparser commands. See the following example:

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument("-H", action="store_true")
subparser = argparser.add_subparsers(dest='sp')
cmd = subparser.add_parser("cmd")
cmd.add_argument("-H")

print argparser.parse_args()
```

Then, running

```
py test.py -H cmd -H 5
```

on the command line gives

```
Namespace(H='5', sp='cmd')
```

I'd hope to instead have something perhaps like

```
Namespace(H=True, sp={'cmd':Namespace(h='5')})
```

Is there a native way to get something like this functionality, or do I have to go through the trouble of building a custom argparser? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is answered here:

[argparse subcommands with nested namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668227/argparse-subcommands-with-nested-namespaces)

One of my answers uses a custom action.

But a simpler way of handling duplicate argument names, is to give one, or both, different 'dest' values.  It distinguishes between the two without extra machinery.

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument("-H", action="store_true")
subparser = argparser.add_subparsers(dest='sp')
cmd = subparser.add_parser("cmd")
cmd.add_argument("-H", dest='cmd_H')

print argparser.parse_args()
```