# Defining common options for sub-commands with plac

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

My question is essentially a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248487/semi-automatic-generation-of-argparsers-for-functions). This shows how you can use `plac` to automatically generate a command-line interface with sub-commands representing each function.

Is it possible to tell `plac` about options which are common to all sub-commands, and could be viewed as 'global' options? In fact, these options should have meaning without a sub-command.

As an example, I might have `svn checkout` and `svn update` sub-commands, but would also like an `svn -v` or `svn --version` command.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I set up a multiprocessing script using `plac`.  It had multiple commands with overlapping sets of arguments.  I'll try to abstract what I did

```
class Interface(object):
    commands = ['fn1','fn2',...]
    dict1 = dict(quiet=(...), dryrun=(...), ...)
    dict2 = dict()
    dict3 = dict()

    dict1.update(dict2)
    @plac.annotations(**dict1)
    def fn1(self, dryrun, quiet, ...)
        ...
    @plac.annotations(foo=(...), **dict2)
    def fn2(self, foo, ...)
        ...
    @plac.annotations(**dict2)
    def fn3(self, ...)
        ...
```

So while the arguments for each function had to be spelled out in full, the annotations could be built by mix and matching various dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty on `plac`, so I'll first address this from a basic `argparse` usage.

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(version='1.2.3')
sp = p.add_subparser()
sp.add_parser('checkout')
sp.add_parser('update')
```

`p.parse_args(['-v'])` returns `1.2.3` and exits.  But `-v` is like `-h`, a special argument.

`p.parse_args([])` though gives a `too few arguments` error.  i.e. it expects a subcommand.  The same would be true if that 'global option' were something like `-d`.

A couple of qualifications:

- new versions specify a 'version' argument in a different way.
- in `3.3`, subcommands are no longer required.  That's due to a change in the required-arguments error message, and may/or might not be true with future changes.

I think these restrictions still apply if the parser is generated by `plac`, but I'd have to review the `plac` code to be sure.